# Xtext cross-references not working correctly?

Tags: xtext, cross-reference

In my dsl I was trying the following:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.Recipe with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate recipe "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/Recipe"


Model:
    recipe=Recipe;


enum Ingredients:
    Meat | Fish | Rice
;

enum Steps_Type:
    Cut | Boil | Prepare
;

Recipe:
    'Recipe'
    '{'
    ingredient+=Ingredient+
    step+=Step+
    '}'
;

Ingredient:
    'ingredient' ingredient_name=Ingredients quantity=INT ('kg' | 'g')
;

Step:
    '['
    step=Steps_Type
    ingredient=[Ingredient]
    ']'
;
```

My problem is on the step. I want only the ingredients I've declared on the Recipe to appear.
For example if I do this:

```
Recipe {
    ingredient Fish 1 kg
    ingredient Meat 2kg
    [
        Cut

    ]
}
```

Below cut I only want fish and meat to appear as options.

I've read about cross-references but I can't get it to work while using an enum to limit user input.

Answer (score 0):

Xtext can reference things with `name`s only. you dont have `name`s,  you have `ingredient_name`. also names have to be Strings by default. => You have to implement `IQualifiedNameProvider` (usually a subclass of DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider`) https://www.dietrich-it.de/xtext/2011/07/16/iqualifiednameproviders-in-xtext-2-0.html

Comment: How can I achieve that? I've tried switching the ingredient_name for name and [Ingredient] to [Ingredient|STRING]

Do I have to implement code outside the grammar?

Comment: this is not what i mean: name=ID with ref=[Ingredient]
or you simply implement the IQualifiedNameProvider

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I'm kinda lost

Comment: I can get it working if I have an ID however I didn't want to use one

Comment: again: implement IQualifiedNameProvider (and use a Datatype rule to cope with keywords from enum)

Comment: I understend that, and I tried copying the example from the link you provided however I can't manage to get it working, it always says that enum is not a string and changing it to returns EString or similar doesnt work

Comment: i meant `MyID: ID | "Meat" | "Fish" | "Rice"` with `someref=[Ingredient| MyID]`

Comment: Yes but that's using an ID, which I didn't want to use

Comment: then leave out the ID

Comment: That gives me the error: "the rule 'Ingredients' is not valid for a cross reference since it does not return an EString. You'll have to wrap it in a data type rule"